# Unable to require ERC-20 tokens in a Solidity function

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, openzeppelin

I have a basic ERC-20 `Token` defined as

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Token is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("Token", "TOKEN") {}

    function mint(address account, uint256 amount) public {
        _mint(account, amount);
    }
}
```

I have another contract `Item` that has a method I want to cost `1 Token`, basing answer off https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/78911/30804

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract Item {
    IERC20 private token;

    constructor(address tokenAddress) {
        token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
    }

    function myMethod() public {
        bool success = token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), 1 ether); // also tried just 1
        require(success, "Insufficient Funds: Requires 1 Token");
        // do things
    }
}
```

I'm running this inside a Hardhat test

```
  const TokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
  Token = await Token.deploy();
  await Token.mint(owner.address, ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", 18));
  await Token.approve(owner.address, ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", 18));

  const ItemFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("Item");
  Item = await ItemFactory.deploy(Token.address);
  await Item.myMethod(); // this is the line that errors
```

Everything runs and I can see debug code from the solidity contracts, but I keep getting an error that

> reverted with reason string 'ERC20: insufficient allowance'

that I traced back to the openzeppelin internal function `_spendAllowance`

After some debugging I thought that the culprit was because I needed to approve, so I added a call to approve but I'm still getting the same error

I'm assuming my issue is something basic can anyone see what it might be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
await Token.approve(owner.address, ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", 18));
```

You're giving the approval to the `owner` address, but the actual `msg.sender` inside the `transferFrom()` function is the `Item` address (as the caller of the function is the `Item` contract).

Solution: Approve the `Item` address as the spender.

```
// after the `Item` contract has been deployed
await Token.approve(Item.address, ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", 18));
await Item.myMethod();
```